# Symfony 2.6 - embedding a collection of forms (ManyToMany)

Tags: javascript, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

I have two entities, *cases* and *tags*, with a many-to-many relationship.

- Case entity -

`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="case", cascade={"persist"})
 private $tags;`

- Tag entity -

`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Case", mappedBy="tags")
 private $case;`

This is working fine when I add tags through check-boxes. But I want to add new tags (many of them) through collection of forms.

I'm following symfony cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

- CaseType.php -

`$builder
            ->add('title')
            //...
            ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TagType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ));`

- new.html.twig -

`{{ form_start(form) }}
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype.name)|e }}">
     {% for tag in form.tags %}
  <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
  </ul>{{ form_end(form) }}`

Here is JavaScript code from new.html.twig, working: http://jsfiddle.net/7d8vLokn/1/

Problem is when the new.html.twig is rendered, it shows only Tag label, nothing else, on the bottom of the page.

[image]

### Edit

I noticed that there are two data-prototypes in new.html.twig, one which I created (mentioned above), and one created automatically, on the bottom of the page... empty:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Tags</label>
    <div id="my_bundle_bug_tags" data-prototype=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your entity doesn't have any tag yet, it's normal to view only the "tags" label.

Comment: @Veve I previously added few tags in database by hand.